# How to export the tcpdump result running in real-time on a remote machine into a pcap file on my computer?

Tags: c, python-3.x, multithreading, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I have a Wi-Fi probe which I would manage. In a thread, I have to run a tcpdump by SSH and to get result through the ssh tunnel and write it into a pcap file on my own computer.

Now, I run the tcpdump command and I get back the result but I don't know how to write it into a PCAP file and I don't really what is the type of data that I get back.

```
self.dataSSH=self.TunnelSSH_data.OuvrirTunnelSSH() #self.dataSSH is a paramiko.SSHClient object
sin, sout, serr = self.dataSSH.exec_command(self.ssh_command, get_pty=True)

while self.running :
   for l in self.line_buffered(sout):
      print(l)

def line_buffered(self,f):
  line_buf = ""
  while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():
      line_buf += to_unicode(f.read(1))
      if line_buf.endswith('\n'):
          yield line_buf
          line_buf = ''
```

The content of ssh_command is :

```
"tcpdump -i " + <Interface to monitor> + " -B 8192 -s 500 -U -n -w -"
```

Today, I just print the results in unicode but I don't know how to write it in pcap file.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see the code that calls "tcpdump" to give you a clear answer, but you should know that "tcpdump" already gives you the option to write the results into a ".pcap" file. Example:

`tcpdump -s 0 port ftp or ssh -i eth0 -w mycap.pcap`

The code above dumps the results into "mycap.pcap" (taken from https://linuxexplore.com/2012/06/07/use-tcpdump-to-capture-in-a-pcap-file-wireshark-dump/ ).

So what I would try is generating the pcap in the probe, then transfer the pcap trace to your computer, and then removing the pcap file off the probe's disk if that's really needed.

Comment: I know this option with tcpdump, but the probe doesn't have enough memory to save a pcap file so I have to create the file somewhere else...